# Creating a WP archive with custom field filter

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

So I'am trying to create a filter with Advanced Custom Filters Pro plugin, on the custom post type archive page, but it doesn't filter. It changes the URL although it lists all item on the page no matter the selection.

I'm trying to replicate following this tutorial: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-wp-archive-custom-field-filter/

I have set up functions.php with the following:

```
<?php

function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'aerious-parent-stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( 'aerious-google-fonts', 'aerious-libs' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );

function aerious_child_lang_setup() {
    $lang = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages';
    load_child_theme_textdomain( 'aerious', $lang );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'aerious_child_lang_setup' );


// Houses Custom Posttype

$labels = array(
    'name'                  => 'Houses',
    'singular_name'         => 'House',
    'add_new'               => 'Add New',
    'add_new_item'          => 'Add New House',
    'edit_item'             => 'Edit Houses',
    'new_item'              => 'New House',
    'all_items'             => 'All Houses',
    'view_item'             => 'View House',
    'search_items'          => 'Search Houses',
    'not_found'             => 'No houses found',
    'not_found_in_trash'    => 'No houses found in Trash',
    'parent_item_colon'     => '',
    'menu_name'             => 'Houses',

);


$args = array(
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'public'                => true,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'query_var'             => true,
    'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'houses' ),
    'capability_type'       => 'post',
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'supports'              => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnal')
);

register_post_type( 'house', $args);

// Custom Posttype Filter

// array of filters (field key => field name)
$GLOBALS['my_query_filters'] = array( 
    'field_5d1cafdb2f7d4'   => 'bedrooms'   
);


// action
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts', 10, 1);

function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    // bail early if is in admin
    if( is_admin() ) return;


    // bail early if not main query
    // - allows custom code / plugins to continue working
    if( !$query->is_main_query() ) return;


    // get meta query
    $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');


    // loop over filters
    foreach( $GLOBALS['my_query_filters'] as $key => $name ) {

        // continue if not found in url
        if( empty($_GET[ $name ]) ) {

            continue;

        }


        // get the value for this filter
        // eg: http://www.website.com/events?city=melbourne,sydney
        $value = explode(',', $_GET[ $name ]);


        // append meta query
        $meta_query = array(
            'key'       => $name,
            'value'     => $value,
            'compare'   => 'IN',
        );


    } 


    // update meta query
    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
    // echo '<pre>';
    // var_dump($query->query_vars);
    // echo '</pre>';
}
```

And within my archive-house.php:

```
<?php

global $aerious_options;

get_header();

do_action( 'aerious_main_layout_start' );

$class_blog_layout  = isset( $aerious_options['blog_layout'] ) ? esc_html( $aerious_options['blog_layout'] ) : 'standard';
$classes = array( 'aerious-blog-posts', 'blog-layout-'. $class_blog_layout );

$blog_pagination_type = isset( $aerious_options['blog_pagination_type'] ) ? esc_attr( $aerious_options['blog_pagination_type'] ) : 'pagination';
$blog_archive_layout = isset( $aerious_options['blog_archive_layout'] ) ? esc_attr( $aerious_options['blog_archive_layout'] ) : 'standard';

if ( $blog_pagination_type == 'loadmore' ) {
    $classes[] = 'pagination-container';
}
else {
    $classes[] = 'row';
}

if( $class_blog_layout == 'grid' ) {
    $classes[] = 'posts-grid';
}


if ( have_posts() ){ ?>
    <div <?php echo aerious_class( $classes ) ?> >

    <!-- FILTER START -->   
    <div id="archive-filters">
        <?php foreach( $GLOBALS['my_query_filters'] as $key => $name ): 

            // get the field's settings without attempting to load a value
            $field = get_field_object($key, false, false);


            // set value if available
            if( isset($_GET[ $name ]) ) {

                $field['value'] = explode(',', $_GET[ $name ]);

            }


            // create filter
            ?>
            <div class="filter" data-filter="<?php echo $name; ?>">
                <?php create_field( $field ); ?>
            </div>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {

        // change
        $('#archive-filters').on('change', 'input[type="radio"]', function(){

            // vars
            var url = '<?php echo home_url('houses'); ?>';
                args = {};


            // loop over filters
            $('#archive-filters .filter').each(function(){

                // vars
                var filter = $(this).data('filter'),
                    vals = [];


                // find checked inputs
                $(this).find('input:checked').each(function(){

                    vals.push( $(this).val() );

                });


                // append to args
                args[ filter ] = vals.join(',');

            });


            // update url
            url += '?';


            // loop over args
            $.each(args, function( name, value ){

                url += name + '=' + value + '&';

            });


            // remove last &
            url = url.slice(0, -1);


            // reload page
            window.location.replace( url );


        });

    })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <!-- FILTER END --> 

        <?php

        if ( $blog_pagination_type == 'loadmore' OR $blog_archive_layout == 'grid' )  : ?>
            <div class="<?php if ( $blog_pagination_type == 'loadmore' ) { echo 'posts-append grid row'; } else { echo 'grid'; } ?>"> <?php
        endif;
            while ( have_posts() ) { the_post();
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/blog/content', 'loop' );
            }
        if ( $blog_pagination_type == 'loadmore' OR $blog_archive_layout == 'grid' )  : ?>
        </div><?php
        endif;

        if ( $blog_pagination_type == 'loadmore' ) {
            $big = 999999999;
            $loadmore_text = ( isset( $aerious_options['loadmore_text'] ) && $aerious_options['loadmore_text'] ) ? esc_html( $aerious_options['loadmore_text'] ) : esc_html__( 'Load More', 'aerious' );
            echo '<div class="pagination-loadmore">';
            echo  paginate_links( array(
                   'base'       => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                   'format'     => '?paged=%#%',
                   'current'    => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
                   'total'      => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
                   'next_text'  => '<span class="aerious-btn aerious-btn-default aerious-btn-lg">'. $loadmore_text .'<span class="aerious-count-loader"><img src="'. get_template_directory_uri(). "/assets/images/loaders/loader.gif" .'" alt="..."></span></span>',
               ) );
            echo '</div>';
        }
        else {
            aerious_pagination();
        }
        ?>
    </div> <?php
}
else {
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content','none' );
}

do_action( 'aerious_main_layout_end' );

get_footer();
```

The search address is:

```
https://startnow.hu/houses/?bedrooms=1,3
```

DEBUG with:

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($wp_query->query_vars); echo "</pre>";
```

Result:

```
array(54) {
  ["post_type"]=>
  string(5) "house"
  ["error"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["m"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["p"]=>
  int(0)
  ["post_parent"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["subpost"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["subpost_id"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["attachment"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["attachment_id"]=>
  int(0)
  ["name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["static"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["pagename"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["page_id"]=>
  int(0)
  ["second"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["minute"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["hour"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["day"]=>
  int(0)
  ["monthnum"]=>
  int(0)
  ["year"]=>
  int(0)
  ["w"]=>
  int(0)
  ["category_name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["tag"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["cat"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["tag_id"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["author"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["author_name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["feed"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["tb"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["paged"]=>
  int(0)
  ["meta_key"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["meta_value"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["preview"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["s"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["sentence"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["title"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["fields"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["menu_order"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["embed"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["category__in"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["category__not_in"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["category__and"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["post__in"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["post__not_in"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["post_name__in"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["tag__in"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["tag__not_in"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["tag__and"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["tag_slug__in"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["tag_slug__and"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["post_parent__in"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["post_parent__not_in"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["author__in"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["author__not_in"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["meta_query"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(8) "bedrooms"
    ["value"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
    ["compare"]=>
    string(2) "IN"
  }
}
NULL
```

Comment: I answered a question about this tutorial a while ago, might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55783399/wordpress-archive-page-with-filter-doesnt-work-acf/55935248#55935248

Comment: Hello Paul thank you for your answer, I've looked at your solution before, unfortunately I can't get my head around. Its only changing the url for me.

Comment: Anyway I've changed radio to select replacing This::: 

`$('#archive-filters').on('change', 'input[type="select"]', function(){` to this

`$('#archive-filters').on('change', 'select', function(){` and this `$(this).find('input:checked').each(function(){` to this `$(this).find('option:checked').each(function(){` .. Url changes but the content doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I've solved the problem!

In the functions.php the tutorial said to write

```
// append meta query
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => $name,
            'value'     => $value,
            'compare'   => 'IN',
        );
```

but instead we need

```
// append meta query
        $meta_query = [];
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => $name,
            'value'     => $value,
            'compare'   => 'IN',
        );
```

Thanks for the help anyway!